# My laptop won't turn off with the power button

Tags: windows-7, laptop

I have a new laptop, and I would like the power button to shut down windows.  The power button turns on OK, and it turns the laptop off if I hold it down for 5 seconds, but I want a nice windows shutdown.  I have checked the Control Panel settings, and the Power Button is set to "Shut-down" for both battery and plugged in modes.

It's an Acer laptop running Windows 7.  My old Acer laptop was fine for the shutdown, but the new one just won't do it.  The Sleep button (Fn F4) also does nothing, but all the other Fn keys seem to work.

Is there anything else I can check?

Comment: Make sure you are modifying power settings for current plan.
Also, check when you want to shutdown your laptop, the current power plan should have the same setting i.e. power button to shutdown.

Comment: try ALT+F4 this will give an option to shut down

Answer (score 1):

Answer is in the comments of Original Post

> Aha, yes, for some reason, the power button action was not showing the
>   current power plan (plugged in), but one of the others. By going into
>   the advanced power plan settings, I discovered that the current power
>   plan had the power button disabled! Fixed now, thanks! – user1961169